# Union queries from different databases in Laravel Query Builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have two similar tables in two different databases. Both tables have a column with a date and one with  email addresses. Though the column names are not the same. As result I want to have one result that contains all records from both tables.

So my first step is:

```
$emails_1 = DB::connection('db1')->table('contacts_1')->select('mail_address AS email', 'date as created_at');
$emails_2 = DB::connection('db2')->table('contacts_2')->select('email', 'created_at');
```

So now I have two results and the column names in the result are equal (email and created_at).

Now I want to merge the results together, so I do:

```
$all_emails = $emails_1->union($emails_2);
```

And this is where I get the error:

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db1.contacts_2' doesn't
>   exist (SQL: (select `mail_address` as `email`, `date` as `created_at`
>   from `contacts_1`) union (select `email`, `created_at` from
>   `contacts_2`))

So it seems that query builder gets confused with the diferente tables.

Has anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use different connections, but you still can do it providing the db name explicitly:

```
$q1 = DB::table('db1.contacts')
       // where(..) or anything you need here
       ->select('mail_address as email', 'date as created_at');

$q2 = DB::table('db2.contacts')
       // like above
       ->select('email', 'created_at');

$result = $q2->union($q1)->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do a UNION query across connections. You'll have to do it as two separate queries:

```php
$emails1 = DB::connection('db1')->table('contacts_1')
             ->selectRaw('mail_address as email, date as created_at')->get();

$emails2 = DB::connection('db2')->table('contacts_2')
             ->select('email', 'created_at')->get();

$emails = array_merge($emails1, $emails2);
```

Comment: Is $emails this way still a DB instance where I can do things like $emails->where('...')->get(); ?

Comment: @almo - Nope. `$emails` is a simple array. If you want to add more constraints, you'll have to add it to both queries separately.

Comment: do not use array_merge, its not proper

Comment: not good practice. the query is execured twice instead of once.